# LINQ: From a list of type T, retrieve only objects of a certain subclass S

Tags: c#, linq, typeof, oftype

Given a simple inheritance hierarchy:
Person -> Student, Teacher, Staff

Say I have a list of Persons, L.
In that list are some Students, Teachers, and Staff.

Using LINQ and C#, is there a way I could write a method that could retrieve only a particular type of person?

I know I can do something like:

```
var peopleIWant = L.OfType< Teacher >();
```

But I want to be able to do something more dynamic.  I would like to write a method that will retrieve results for any type of Person I could think of, without having to write a method for every possible type.

Comment: Why no create a generic method ?

Comment: I think that's what Mladen Prajdic, did.  I hadn't even thought of it, but now that I see it, it seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you can do this:

```
IList<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

public IList<T> GetPersons<T>() where T : Person
{
    return persons.OfType<T>().ToList();
}

IList<Student> students = GetPersons<Student>();
IList<Teacher> teacher = GetPersons<Teacher>();
```

EDIT: added the where constraint.

Comment: Ah, this looks wonderful.  I am new to LINQ, and not particularly well-versed in generics, but this seems to be precisely what I want.  Thank you!.

Comment: No need to call ToList on the result of GetPersons<T>, since it already returns an IList<T>...

Comment: You might want to put a constraint of "where T : Person" just to avoid empty lists due to typos etc.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: yeah i saw that and removed it. thanx.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, could you clarify how I would add such a constraint?  Do you mean to do some kind of check that "T" is really of type Person, as to avoid a possible logical error?  Perhaps a "if(T is Person)" check at the start of this method?

Comment: No, Jon is talking about a generic type constraint, which is checked at compile time, not runtime. See this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Am I missing something here?  It seems like all we did here was make the call to OfType into a redundant method.

Comment: I'm not seeing it either.  Didn't you just write a wrapper for the same exact linq method that the OP mentioned?

Comment: @JoeChung @eremzeit - `OfType<T>` compiles for any `T`; `GetPersons<T>` method only compiles when `T : Person`.  Technically not the "exact same" thing; technically not redundant.

Comment: I see:  narrowing the generic type parameter to just be subclasses of type Person.  I would have preferred a version of this answer without the .ToList() call, but it's close enough.

Comment: Use this signature to use this with any class and subclass pair: `public IList<TSub> GetSubs<T, TSub>() where TSub : T { ... }`

Comment: this is just a wrapper around .ToList();

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick.

```
var students = persons.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(Student));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I knew that something like this was possible; I wanted to extend the idea to something more generic.  

Mladen Prajdic suggested I use a Generic Method, which is something that hadn't crossed my mind.

Comment: this is my favorite

Comment: Be aware, that this doesn't handle inheritance. In that case you would need something like `.Where(p => p is Student)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleOfType<T>(IEnumerable<Person> list)
    where T : Person
{
    return list.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(T));
}
```

But all you've really done is rewrite LINQ's OfType() method with a safer version that uses static type checking to ensure you pass in a Person.  You still can't use this method with a type that's determined at runtime (unless you use reflection).

For that, rather than using generics, you'll have to make the type variable a parameter:

```
IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleOfType(IEnumerable<Person> list, Type type)
{
    if (!typeof(Person).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter 'type' is not a Person");

    return list.Where(p => p.GetType() == type);
}
```

Now you can construct some type dynamically and use it to call this method.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the "where" constraint for generics.  As soon as I specified that constraint, I can now rely on Intellisense support on the available methods & properties of my Person type.

Answer (score -1):

For general list, using `delegate`:

```
public List<T> FilterByType(List<T> items, Type filterType)
{
    return items.FindAll(delegate(T t)
    {
        return t.GetType() == filterType;
    });
}
```