# How to retrieve an object of a specific subclass?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class 'Entity', that has a list of 'Component' objects. Now, 'Component' is just a root class for a bunch of different subclasses, and each subclass can be represented only once per entity. Now, I would like to retrieve a certain type of 'Component', how do I do that?

It's a bit difficult to explain, but here's a code example of what I'd like to have:

```
class Component {...} // The root class
class CompA : Component {...} // A type of Component
class Entity { List<Component> components; } // Entity with a list of component

...

Entity entity = new Entity(); // Create a new entity
entity.components.Add(new CompA()); // Add a component of type 'CompA'
CompA c = entity.GetComponent<CompA>(); // This is what I'd like to do :)
```

Comment: Like the [`Enumerable.OfType<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184944/linq-from-a-list-of-type-t-retrieve-only-objects-of-a-certain-subclass-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.Components.OfType<theType>();
```

Comment: @spender yeah, if your list just has one of that type, then .SingleOrDefault()

Comment: Err, List<> doesn't have such method. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @manabreak `IList<T>` does.. interfaces >:) (extension method..)

Comment: @TimJarvis Err... I don't know. All the List<> methods are there, but I get errors if I try to call .OfType<>(). It doesn't show up in the IntelliSense list either.

Comment: @manabreak Just in case my comment wasn't entirely clear.. you'll need to add a reference to `System.Core`, where all of these extension methods are, and a `using System.Linq` to your `using` directives.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Ah, thanks. I was missing the Ling usage there. Thanks. :)

Comment: @TimJarvis: The reason I stated `.SingleOrDefault()` is because the OP stated "each subclass can be represented only once per entity", so it enforces this assertion.