# Pulling objects of different type from MongoDB

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am new to c# and mongodb. Is it possible to use linq to pull an object of a specified type from a mongodb? Basically I want to do something similar to this: [LINQ: From a list of type T, retrieve only objects of a certain subclass S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184944/linq-from-a-list-of-type-t-retrieve-only-objects-of-a-certain-subclass-s/1184962#1184962) but in mongodb and not be limited to inheriting from anything other than object. I need to pull from a prespecified collection which can be assumed to have an object of the relevant type in it.

EDIT
The objects were originally stored as json

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't generically use LINQ to query a collection without a strongly typed base type to work from. It really doesn't add much when you can just use a BsonDocument to query with.

Comment: I am storing several configurations for different aspects of a website that are each different objects. Does that make sense? One stores layout, another data retrieval, another configuration handles security

Comment: You can't do it with LINQ. You need to use strongly typed objects.

Comment: Good to know thanks for your help... Should I just organize the configurations into different collections of the same type?

Comment: They can be in one or more collections. It's up to you. It's really about the query and how you want to index things that is relevant to the layout of your documents.