# Accessing member variable in subclass (C#)

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

All the objects in my game have inherit my **Sprite** class. Here's the hierarchy I'm using:

**Sprite** > **StaticObject** > **MovingObject** > **Character** > **Player**

I have written a function in my main game class that searches through all objects in the game and finds any "**Player**" objects. If a **Player** object is found, it prints to the screen the value of the object's speed (the **v2Speed** vector).

```
foreach (var gameObject in GameInfo.gameInfo.gameObjects)
{
    if (gameObject.GetType() == typeof (Player))
    {
        string sPlayerPosition = string.Format("Player position: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", gameObject.v2Position.X, gameObject.v2Position.Y);
        DrawWithShadow(sPlayerPosition, new Vector2(10, 60));

        string sPlayerSpeed = string.Format("Player speed: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", gameObject.v2Speed.X, gameObject.v2Speed.Y);
        DrawWithShadow(sPlayerSpeed, new Vector2(10, 80));
    }
}
```

However, this only works if I put **v2Speed** in the base **Sprite** class. I assume that this is because the compiler wants to find the variable in every object that the game is searching through. I'm not sure why this is a problem because the code accessing **v2Speed** is only ever applied to a **Player** object, which will always have that vector defined. I really don't want to have **v2Speed** in any class higher than the **MovingObject** class, because the **Sprite** and **StaticObject** objects will never move once the game starts.

My question is how do I rewrite the code above to access **v2Speed** if it is stored in the **MovingObject** class instead of the **Sprite** class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: From a list of type T, retrieve only objects of a certain subclass S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184944/linq-from-a-list-of-type-t-retrieve-only-objects-of-a-certain-subclass-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler only knows that `gameObject` is of type `Sprite` (I assume; it's hard to tell for sure). Your `if` condition doesn't change that.

Instead, you can use:

```
if (gameObject is Player player)
{
    // Now use player instead of gameObject
}
```

Note that this requires C# 7. If you're only using C# 6 or earlier, you'd use:

```
Player player = gameObject as Player;
if (player != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that this behaves slightly differently to your original code - if you had an object which was an instance of a *subclass* of `Player`, it wouldn't be picked up in your original code, but would be in this code... which is probably what you want.

(The `OfType<Player>` approach as per Codor's answer is a great alternative - although I'd then call the loop variable `player` instead of `gameObject`, given that you'd know it was a player...)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon! I don't quite understand why in my original code the compiler only knew that gameObject was of type Sprite. I'd have thought the if statement using `typeof (Player)` would take care of that. I must be missing some knowledge of how that works! Anyway, your code has solved my problem so thank you!

Comment: @AndyLatham: Basically, the compile-time type of a variable doesn't change based on what you do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be changed using Linq as follows.

```
foreach (var gameObject in GameInfo.gameInfo.gameObjects.OfType<Player>())
{
    string sPlayerPosition
        = string.Format("Player position: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", 
                gameObject.v2Position.X, gameObject.v2Position.Y);
                DrawWithShadow(sPlayerPosition, new Vector2(10, 60));

    string sPlayerSpeed
        = string.Format("Player speed: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", 
                gameObject.v2Speed.X, gameObject.v2Speed.Y);
                DrawWithShadow(sPlayerSpeed, new Vector2(10, 80));

}
```

Alternatively, a cast to `Player` could be used inside the loop's body.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a Type Cast, and you should do it using `as` because you don't know for sure if the object is of the `Player` type.

Like this:

```
foreach (var gameObject in GameInfo.gameInfo.gameObjects)
{
    var player = gameObject as Player;  // try to do Type Cast
    if (player != null)             // if true, then Type Cast has succeeded
    {
        string sPlayerPosition = string.Format("Player position: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", player.v2Position.X, player.v2Position.Y);
        DrawWithShadow(sPlayerPosition, new Vector2(10, 60));

        string sPlayerSpeed = string.Format("Player speed: ({0:0.00},{1:0.00})", player.v2Speed.X, player.v2Speed.Y);
        DrawWithShadow(sPlayerSpeed, new Vector2(10, 80));
    }
}
```